# Foreign model not showing up

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a model customer that contains a country class.  Both Country and Customer models are mapped to a database.

```
    [Table("Customer")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Telephone")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

When Trying to generate a list of Customers. It doesn't see to generate the Country Name. even though the all fields are filled when looking in the database.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><input name="select_row[]" type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prefix)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remarks)</td>
                <td><span onclick="function_panel('customer','edit','@Url.Action("Edit", "Customer", new { id = item.CustomerID })')">edit</span>
                     | 
                    <span onclick="function_panel('customer','delete','@Url.Action("Delete","Customer")')">del</span></td>
            </tr>
            }
```

Comment: please post code for how you are querying customers.

Comment: It's just a `db.Customers.ToList()` Where db is a dbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't defined the Country property overridable.try changing you'r model like this :

```
public class Customer
    {
        .
        .            

        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        .
        .

    }
```

or try eager loading your Country as following:

```
var customers = db.Customers.Include("Country").ToList();
```

Comment: I thought by not using virtual I was essentially eager loading?